# Find a Möbius transformation sending 0 and infinity, to -1 and 1.

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis

Find a Möbius transformation sending 0 and infinity, to -1 and 1, hence mapping $y$-axis onto unit semicircle

My thoughts: Since we need to send three points to define the Möbius transformation, we must send $i$ to $i$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider, in general, a Möbius transformation $T(z)=\displaystyle\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ . Since $0$ and $\infty$ are desired to be mapped to $-1$ and $1$, respectively; first  put $0$ in $T(z)$  and get $\displaystyle\frac{b}{d}=-1$ , i.e., $b=-d$. Secondly, put $\infty$(I hope it makes sense) in your $T(z)$ and get $\displaystyle\frac{a}{c}=1$, i.e., $a=c$. Combine these two results and have
                       $T(z)=\displaystyle\frac{az+b}{az-b}$ for any non-zero complex numbers $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Great answer!!!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

What about $z\mapsto \displaystyle\frac{z-1}{z+1}$?

It also maps the imaginary axis to the (*whole*) unit circle, as if $z=yi$, then $|yi-1|=|yi+1|$, and $\ \arg\left(\displaystyle\frac{yi-1}{yi+1}\right)=2\arg(yi-1)$, can be any angle.

Comment: yeah, we need 0 to go to -1

Comment: Ok. Yes, I will think it over..

Comment: I got uncertain.. because of that $-1$, it can't be *any* angle.. so it is possible that we indeed get a *semicircle* only.. but then.. where is the other half coming from?

Comment: upper y axis is mapped to upper semicircle.